# angular js bootstrap tabs with uirouter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create use a ui router for Angularjs bootstrap tab component. Im having issues in getting the content displayed on the page . Below is my code

```
    <div class="container" style="height: 530px;margin-top: 5%;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menuh1">Testing</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#bhistory" ng-click="_redirect('bhistory');">History</a></li>
    </ul>
 <div class="tab-content" style="height: 100%;border: 1px #ddd solid;">
     <div id="menuh1" class="tab-pane fade">    
    </div>
    <div  id="bdhistory" class="tab-pane fade"  >
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Above is the code for the tab and in my controller im updating the state to be routed. Below is the Controller code

```
var navtabs = angular.module("HValidationModule", []).config(
      function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }).controller("HValidationController", function($scope, $http, $location, $state) {


$scope._redirect = function(caseStr) {
    $("#" + $scope.currentActiveTab).removeClass('active');
    $("#" + caseStr).addClass('active');
    $scope.currentActiveTab = caseStr;
    $state.go("bdata."+caseStr);

};
});
```

Below is the code for the router state.

```
  .state(
                        'bdata.bhistory',
                        {
                            url : '/bhistory',
                            templateUrl : '',
                            controller : 'historyController',
                            resolve : {
                                redirectIfNotAuthenticated : _redirectIfNotAuthenticated
                            },
                            views : {
                                '' : {
                                    templateUrl : './resources/app/components/BValidation/HSystem/HHistoryView.html'
                                },
                            }
                        })
```

When I click on the history tab, the application url gets pointed to the above state. But the HHistoryView.html file data is not loaded on the screen.  Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question, but it might help you to not re-invent the wheel and use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs instead.

Comment: Is there an error in the debug console of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

try to delete templateUrl from .state .
by the way jquery-bootstrap in angular has a lot of problems/ ui-bootstrap has none